# connection to firebase auth appcompat-v7:28.0.0 Error

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

When I connect to Firebase Auth I got error in dependencies check this screen shot. How to fix this error?

[image: here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the clashing support libraries by adding the conflicted libraries explicitly in your dependencies block.

```
dependencies {
   implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
   implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
}
```

or you can use the whole support-v4 library which is include all the above libraries:

```
dependencies {
   implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is self explanatory, you are using different versions for each of the following.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
```

Change any one to match another, usually upgrading is better choice.